# Добавить подсказки пользователю о возможности отметки правильного ответа как решения

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Периодически на сайте всплывают старые вопросы в которых есть ответы и они являются решениями, но не отмеченные как решение(нет зеленой галки). Кроме этого такие вопросы висят в ленте/поиске/еще где-либо без принятого ответа и складывается ошибочное впечатление, что по всем данным вопросам нет решения.

Вероятно многие новые участники не читают ни тур, ни тем более справку, а торопятся быстрее задать вопрос и уйти, считая *ru.stackoverflow.com* обычным форумом.

С целью улучшения данной ситуации, предлагаю добавить подсказки пользователю при создании вопроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. В синее поле(линия):

> [Отмечайте ответ
>   как решение вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), если он
>   лучше всего решает именно вашу задачу.

2. В красное поле добавить:

> [Что делать с ответами на мой
>   вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Это тоже не поможет. Люди не читают на дверях таблички "На себя" и "Закрыто", которые висят прямо перед их носом, а какую-то необязательную плашку сбоку формы и подавно не будут. Более менее надёжно стимулирующим решением было бы не давать пользователю задавать новый вопрос, если к его старым вопросам есть ответы с положительным рейтингом, пока он не отметит в них решение или не нажмёт кнопку "Не является решением" с обязательным вводом текста объясняющего, чем именно ответ не устраивает. Но этом может снизить активность.

Comment: Если хоть какая-то часть прочтет и поймет, то уже будет лучше чем сейчас. Что касается стимула и запретов, - Вы предлагаете навязывание действий - это не есть хорошо. Помимо этого решений может быть несколько и вариант с кнопкой будет уже неверным. Ненавязчивое игровое стимулирование в виде новых возможностей и знаков на текущий момнет единственное правильное решение.

Comment: некоторые люди читают (вопрос в том, что в первую очередь показывать). К примеру, [ввод тривиальных опросников для хирургов заметно улучшил результаты операций](http://content.time.com/time/health/article/0,8599,1950892,00.html)

Comment: @jfs это должно быть в добровольной форме, на so(в т.ч. на ru.so) это уже сделано, можно было участвовать в опросе(заполнить анкету) и получить знак [перепись населения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/204/census). А вот что-либо навязывать участнику в обязательной форме торопиться не стоит, в некоторых случаях пряники могут действовать лучше кнута.

Comment: @Alex я не предлагал никому ничего навязывать. Суть комментария, что чтение простых вещей может в принципе помочь и приведён пример когда на практике помогает. Это не значит что нужно в данном конкретном случае что-то навязывать. Посмотрите на мой ответ.

Comment: @jfs читают те, чей мотив - долговременное сотрудничество. Будь это хирурги, делающие свою работу, или постоянные пользователи SO, стремящиеся к улучшению ресурса и личному росту. Те, чей мотив - это получение сиюминутной личной выгоды, читать не будут. А именно последние и создают проблему брошенных ответов.

Comment: Добавлю, что не считаю эту проблему серьёзной. Она есть, но это всего лишь мелкая неприятность, немного снижающая активность авторов ответов.

Comment: @jfs не подразумевалось, что Вы предлагаете навязывание - это всего лишь мнение о ситуации, когда проблема есть (пусть и небольшая), но решать ее нужно осторожно и постепенно, чтобы не навредить. Именно поэтому я и предлагаю пока только добавить больше полезной информации "перед глазами" автора при создании вопроса.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: вы утверждаете, что вообще нету пользы от каких-либо надписей. Я утверждаю, что может быть польза. И если это не ясно: для этого не требуется, чтобы 100% пользователй читали 100% 
 текста на сайте. Если /tour только ~10% процентов пользователей посмотрели, не значит, что выбросить эту страницу надо или что она вообще не нужна. Вообще страницы /help если явно не сослаться, мало кто читает.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, Вы правы проблема не серьезная, но она есть. И хоть она мелкая ее тоже нужно решать)

Comment: @jfs я утверждаю, что польза будет исчезающе малой. Может быть 0.01% от тех, кто сегодня игнорируют выбор ответа, начнут ответы принимать. Конечно же, я могу и ошибаться в оценке процентного соотношения.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: Для ясности: подсказки, которые не являются немедленно полезными лучше избегать, поэтому я не предлагаю *при создании вопроса* упоминать принятие вопроса (см. мой ответ). Но утверждать что подсказки вообще не работают это необоснованно пессимистично (если многие решения имеют плохой UX это не значит, что невозможно грамотный UI создать: к примеру, вместо табличек "от себя", автоматические двери могут использоваться или просто ручки убрать, чтобы только толкать можно было).

Answer (score 3):

**Кратко:** задавая вопрос, авторам вопросов уже и так многими вещами жонглировать приходится, поэтому не стоит их нагружать подробностями, которые не актуальны в данный момент и только позже понадобятся. Подсказка о принятии ответа при задании вопроса была бы скорее бесполезна и даже вредна.

---

Чтобы вопросы не висели неотвеченными, достаточно плюс поставить хорошему ответу. Принятие ответа автором вовсе необязательно, тем более оно просто означает, что ответ автору приглянулся по любым причинам (это не значит, что ответ лучший или правильный).

Внимание автора вопроса ограничено, а Stack Overflow является сложным сайтом, сложный интерфейс (всякие стрелочки, кнопочки, галочки, много текста), не говоря о кучи правил о том 
какие вопросы приветствуются, которые даже опытные участники не все знают. Стоит направить ограниченный ресурс на подсказки по созданию самого вопроса для начала.

При повторных посещениях, или по почте спустя несколько дней, можно автору подсказать, что есть возможность отметить ответ, который ему лично помог или оставить комментарии, если не удаётся из ответов решение получить.

Comment: речь идет о вопросах без принятого ответа, не о вопросах без ответа, а также о том, чтобы повысить доступность информации. Напоминания по почте в теории хорошо, но на это как раз таки нужны ресурсы, а на добавление нескольких информационных строчек ресурсов не нужно. Данное предложение направлено на то, чтобы участник, задавая вопрос, сразу видел нужные ссылки на информацию не только о том, как задать вопрос, но и что делать с ответами на вопрос.

Comment: @Alex вы сказали что  "всплывают старые вопросы", "висят в ленте", "нет решения" — к какой категории по вашему эти вопросы относятся (на SO вопросы с принятыми *или* одобренными ответами не входят в категорию неотвеченных). К тому же ответ явно и принятие ответов затрагивает. Нужно думать зачем галка у ответа — какую информацию несёт, кому от этого польза¶ Во многих вопросах даже форматирования нормального нет.  Так что если подсказки помещать, то следует приоритеты расставлять (весь help в подсказки не поместишь — следует выбирать).

Comment: под лентой подразумевалась главная страница, поиск и другие разделы где могут отображаться вопросы без принятого ответа. Галка говорит о том, что именно данный ответ помог автору(является решением его вопроса). Это не говорит о том, что принятый ответ самый лучший, отнюдь, иногда бывает, что у не принятого ответа рейтинг гораздо выше. Также бывает ситуация когда в виду времени появляется лучшее решение, чем отмеченное.

Comment: Т.е. сама галка по сути говорит все участникам, что если возник подобный вопрос, то именно ответ с галкой является наиболее полезным для решения вопроса, а в идеале и есть решение вопроса. А если участник не торопится, то он прочитает и сравнит решение с другими ответами с хорошим рейтингом и сделает правильный выбор. Текущая проблема в том, что имеются хорошие ответы, а отмеченных как решение вопроса нет - если смотреть на логику so (в  т.ч. прочитать тур), складывается ошибочное впечатление, что ни один ответ не является решением вопроса, а это не так.

Comment: @Alex: "галка" не говорит, что это самый полезный вопрос. Начните с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: я не писал, что "*это самый полезный вопрос*". *...именно ответ с галкой является наиболее полезным для решения вопроса...* - если Вы об этом, то здесь речь об авторе конечно, а не в отношении всех.

Comment: Не понял посыла ответа. Посыл в том, что запрашиваемая функциональность добавления подсказки не нужна?

Comment: Так а разве по почте нету уведомлений, если на ваш вопрос вы ответ не поставили в течении некоторого времени, раньше мне регулярно такие приходили, причём на один вопрос по-моему даже несколько писем приходило через разные промежутки времени.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: да и по почте и комментарии люди оставляют (я не знаю включена по умолчанию рассылка сейчас) -- это просто список альтернатив (реализован он или нет -- здесь не так важно).

Comment: *Stack Overflow является сложным сайтом, сложный интерфейс (всякие стрелочки, кнопочки, галочки, много текста)* - как по мне, так это очень простой в использовании сайт для функционала, который есть. Что касается кучи правил, то правила нужно **читать** и предлагаемое решение позволяет сразу ознакомиться с **нужными** правилами, например не каждый новый участник может знать, что ему делать с ответами, а +1 поставить новый участник не может. Вы так относитесь к предложению, как будто оно включает в себя предложение повесить баннер на полстраницы )

Comment: @Alex: вы посмотрите сколько вопросов закрывается и с минусами -- очевидно, что авторам вопросов больше о содержимом вопросов следует думать, а что делать когда удовлетворительный ответ люди получат, можно и позже напомнить (как я явно в ответе сказал). Дело в приоритетах -- внимание у людей -- это конечный ресурс -- дефицит в данном случае. Есть более приоритетная информация (выдержки из [ask], [mcve]), которую в первую очередь донести следует.

Comment: @jfs они всегда были есть и будут. В этом виноваты лень и "хочу/надо прямо сейчас" - некоторые леняться не только пройтись по поиску, но даже оформить ответ правильно и такие вряд ли вообще будут читать что-то. И это печально. Что касается фокусировки внимания - предлагаемое размещение дополнительной  информации внизу, т.е. на нее участник обратит  внимание если прочтет что-то сверху и ее мало нет предложения добавить много текста, это также важно.

Comment: @jfs Поэтому, хотя Вы говорите правильные в целом вещи, не думаю, что возможен вред. Меня лично беспокоит другое - когда заходишь в вопрос с ответами без принятого решения, чтобы помочь и видишь под каким-либо ответом что-то вроде "*спасибо, супер помогло*", а галки нет. И в очередной раз  понимаешь, что пара минут, которая могла быть отдана другому вопросу прошла зря. А тем кто пришел "на 1 раз и побыстрее" и ленится оформить вопрос вряд ли хоть что-то с первого раза поможет.

Comment: @jfs по поводу содержимого тоже нужно думать, хорошо бы сделать так, чтобы новый участник сам захотел прочитать справку или хотя бы тур, без первого кнута по плохому вопросу. Однако на текущий момент, насколько известно, хорошего решения нет.

Comment: "*При повторных посещениях, или по почте спустя несколько дней, можно автору подсказать, что есть возможность отметить ответ, который ему лично помог или оставить комментарии, если не удаётся из ответов решение получить.*" - неплохая, логичная мысль...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант для размышлений: давать какое-то время автору вопроса на принятие ответа, а после определенного срока предоставлять такое право пользователям с золотым знаком по данной метке?

Comment: На мой взгляд, на этот вопрос есть [прекрасный ответ в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer): *Принятие ответа не означает, что на вопрос был дан идеальный или лучший ответ, оно свидетельствует лишь о том, что автору было предложено решение, которое помогло лично ему. И даже если поступят новые, более правильные ответы, автор вопроса может не поменять своего мнения и оставить принятым тот ответ, который был дан ранее.* Ни модераторы, ни участники с золотой меткой не могут решить за автора вопроса, какой ответ ему помог.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вопрос ведь изначально стоял о том, что имеются незакрытые вопросы. Если автор не пишет даже комментарий "этот ответ не помог", или если вопрос сформулирован неверно, так что абсолютно верный ответ не в состоянии ему помочь - что тогда? Если вопрос реально сто'ящий и среди ответов есть такой, который действительно лучше, полнее других отвечает на данный вопрос - почему через пару месяцев - мне кажется, достаточно времени, чтобы убедиться, что автор не собирается возвращаться к данному вопросу - не дать вопросу статус закрытого?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я же не призываю огульно закрывать все вопросы автоматически. Но когда вопрос таков, что правильный ответ предельно ясен - то, думаю, его можно закрыть. В любом случае я не внес конкретное предложение, а предложил лишь вариант для размышлений, не более того :)

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, немного похожий механизм на то, о чем вы говорите, уже имеется: на сайте есть (1) «неотвеченные» и (2) «без ответа». (1) — это вопросы, в которых нет принятых ответов или ответов с голосом «за». (2) — вопросы без ответов. Таким образом, если другие участники голосуют за какой–либо ответ, вопрос должен пропасть из «неотвеченных».

Comment: Ну, значит, мое предложение несвоевременное :) Я на нем и не настаиваю. Но, как в анекдоте - "неаккуратненько как-то", когда висит двухлетней давности вопрос, например, в списке "похожие" - вроде как без ответа (не зеленый). Заходишь, а там уже давно есть отличный ответ - ни добавить, ни убрать - но просто почему-то не отмеченный птичкой... Кстати, раз вопрос о вопросах :) задан - ну, который мы обсуждаем - "*Добавить подсказки пользователю о возможности отметки правильного ответа как решения*" - значит, проблема имеется?