# Вопросы без меток решено, но с ответами

Tags: предложение, ответы

Предложение по вопросам, на которые дали ответы, но они до сих пор не помечены как решенные:

Что если, участнику блокировать возможность задавать новые вопросы, если на его старые вопросы, у которых есть ответы - не обозначен статус решён/не решён?

Наверное, я не первый, кто задал подобный вопрос [Добавить подсказки пользователю о возможности отметки правильного ответа как решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6972/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88)

Comment: Даже если есть ответы — не факт что они помогли спрашивающему

Comment: @АндрейNOP - статус решен/не решен. Если ответ не помог человеку, пометить его как неверный.

Comment: Но это не значит что ответ неверный :) Считайте так — если ответ не принят, значит вопрос не решен. И тогда волшебным образом то что вы хотите уже есть :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP вы безусловно правы, но я скорее склонялся к забывчивости пользователей. Особенно это касается новичков.

Comment: Наверное тут дело в том, что вам баллы не начислились ) . Забейте на них. Помогли человеку и хорошо. Так даже интереснее этот квест проходить.

Comment: Ну и остальным не важно, есть там метка или нет. Пришедшему из гугла может помочь другой ответ или комментарий какой-нибудь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...по вопросам, на которые дали ответы, но они до сих пор не помечены
> как решенные.

Да, такое бывает часто. И, на мой взгляд, чаще всего это - "залётные птицы", которые, как правило, обратились на ruSO за помощью разок, потому что им нужно срочно решить некую задачу, которую им задали, например, в учебном заведении. Ты готовишь для вновь появившегося участника ответ, выделяешь на это своё драгоценное время. А в результате не получаешь заветной галочки, а порой даже и банального спасибо. Вы об этом?

Сразу оговорюсь, что не для всех галочка - это цель номер один, а спасибо - самоудовлетворение. Например я не отношусь к числу тех, для кого очень важен набор высокой репутации и наибольшее число принятых ответов. Спасибо для меня также не важно, слышу я его и так довольно часто и в реальной жизни. Мне кажется, что здесь важнее другое. А именно - знать, оказался ли твой ответ полезен этому новому участнику, или нет. И поэтому, достаточно только получить от такого участника хотя бы какой-нибудь реакции: "понял-принял" или чего-то другого. Ну то есть, нужен диалог, а не монолог. И довольно часто бывает, что это - монолог. Вот это, как мне кажется, единственный неприятный момент - быть в неведении, пригодилась ли твоя помощь человеку или нет. Так что каждый решает сам, отвечать ему на вопрос, или нет.

Если же для вас важна репутация, то не стоит забывать, что галочка дает вам лишь 15 балов репутации. Однако, если ваш ответ интересный, качественный и главное полезный, то другие участники не пожалеют своего голоса, и каждый такой участник подарит вам по 10 балов репутации, что в сумме может быть достаточно много.

Но не гонитесь за репутацией. Главное - это помощь ближнему, которая заключается в данном случае в ваших интересных, качественных и полезных ответах. И если таковых будет много, то репутация сама вас догонит.

И напоследок, хочется отметить, что такие залётные птички со временем иногда возвращаются. Смотришь, а у тебя принятый ответ. А иногда даже и комментарий с благодарностью. Открываешь, а это было уже давно. Так что живите, радуйтесь и помогайте людям. Остальное приложится.

А вот этого:

> Что если, участнику блокировать возможность задавать новые вопросы,
> если на его старые вопросы, у которых есть ответы - не обозначен
> статус решен/не решен.

не надо. Очень плохая затея. Это уже называется не помощь, а - вред. К тому же, мы не вправе кому-то что-то запрещать. Мы должны быть открыты для всех без каких-либо ограничений.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за развернутый ответ и пояснение =)

Comment: @PerfectVoyage, да всегда пожалуйста. Просто высказал свое личное мнение и мысли по этому поводу. Успехов!

Comment: Но галочка не только для автора, но и для других людей, нашедших вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а мне вот иногда встречаются вопросы, у которых несколько ответов. И я не всегда могу согласится с тем ответом, где галочка. И даже дело не в том, что для автора именно этот ответ с галочкой полностью решает его поставленную задачу. Я понимаю, что автор не настолько опытен, и его вопрос понимаю больше, чем он сам его понимает, чтобы принять правильный ответ. И замечаю, что в ответе с галочкой кроется ошибка, которая потом для него вылезет в самый неподходящий момент. А вот соседний ответ без галочки - это идеальное для него решение. Галочка не всегда есть правильно. Согласитесь?)

Comment: Ну да, бывает, что не туда ставят. Но тем не менее в движок заложено держать ответ с галочкой на первом месте независимо от сортировки (если он не от автора вопроса).

Comment: @Qwertiy, и это логически правильно держать ответ с галочкой на первом месте. Априори формально он как бы самый верный, что в движке и заложено. Только вот в интересах самого участника не доверять системе, если ему нужно безошибочное решение. Как говорится: доверяй, но проверяй. Ну здесь уже каждый должен сам для себя принимать решение. Типа SO ответственности за ваш выбор не несет))

Answer (score 3):

- Если вопрос решен для ТС — то ТС должен поставить галочку.
- Если вопрос не решен для ТС — то ТС не должен ставить галочку.

Ключевое тут: "для ТС". Непринятый ответ вполне может быть полезным. И наоборот. По разным причинам, например:

- ТС не знает/забыл поставить галочку.
- Лучший ответ был написан, когда ТС ушел с сайта (типично для enSO, там надо смотреть на рейтинг ответа, а не на галочку).
- У ТС и у ищущего ответ разные, но схожие ситуации (ну например разные дистры).
- и т.д.

Проблема с непоставленной галочкой в том, что автор помогшего ответа не получает +15 за галочку, хотя хороший ответ все равно "окупится".

> Что если, участнику блокировать возможность задавать новые вопросы, если на его старые вопросы, у которых есть ответы - не обозначен статус решен/не решен.

- Ага, и он будет не понимать "почему я не могу спросить еще?" — и не будет спрашивать.
- Здесь нет статуса "не решен": если нет галочки — то это и значит не решён.

В общем я считаю такое предложение неправильным и слегка не ясным т.к. нет статуса "не решен".

Comment: Статуса нет, но при желании можно добавить.